# Objective C - NSURL - Quotation mark

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurlconnection, nsurl, quotation-marks

I have searched the website for answer without result so here I am with a question.

I am using CouchDB and i'm going to use a view but the problem is that I can't use quotation mark (") in an `NSURL` when I'm creating a url for `NSURLConnection`.

Here's my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:5984/users/_design/search/_view/phone?key=\"0701010100\""]];
```

CouchDB thinks it's a number if I don't use these quotation marks.

Thanks to all for your help.

Marcus

Answer (score 1):

use [-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://127.0.0.1:5984/users/_design/search/_view/phone?key=\"0701010100\""] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I did it by typing %%22 before and after the key-value. But I think I will use your code instead. ;)